# Hide tabbar and navigationbar when view is tapped in monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

I need to be able to hide the navbar and tabbar when I tap on the view and show it again when tapped again. Is this possible in Monotouch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything that is possible with the native platform is possible with MonoTouch.

There are dozens of ways of achieving this.    Perhaps the simplest thing to do is to create your own UIViewController that will host only the information you want and calling:

```
var myNewController = new MyNewController ()
myNewController.View.TouchDown += delegate {
    myNewController.DismissViewControllerAnimated (false);
};
PresentModalViewController (yourNewController, false);
```

Then your myNewController must contain some code to add the actual contents that you want to show in full screen.

Comment: just to clarify, 1) create a `UIViewController` called e.g. `contentController` that contains the content I want to show in full screen, e.g a `UILabel`. 2) within a different `UIViewController` I call then the above code? If so, it seems that `View.TouchDown` is not a valid method. Probably just me not getting it....

Comment: you need a new class, MyNewController.